# Install Apache Mac El Capitan

Tags: apache, installation, osx-elcapitan

I have been trying to set up apache on my mac. I am currently running OSX El Capitan version 10.11.5. I am quite confused because I have read mac comes shipped with Apache.

When I run

```
sudo apachetl start
```

I get the following

```
-bash: apachetl: command not found
```

Comment: You have a typo in your command - `sudo apachectl start`

Comment: This guide is typically pretty good - https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/